# Would there be compatibility issues upgrading rails 2 to rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

Im considering upgrading a rails 2 app to rails 3 for a number of reasons (rails 3 features, certain plugins require rails 3 etc.)

Obviously ill have to update/grade some of the plugins as well. But concerning the code itself, should there be any compatibility issues when upgrading to 3? I know rails 3 changes a lot of helpers and syntax to make things easier, but do the older and more complicated ways still work (ex. gems in envioronment.rb, not Gemfile).

Also, anyone know a good tutorial on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this plugin to check your application compatibility in Rails 3. https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I have written a [blogpost](http://www.dixis.com/?p=463) about it, where I point to the standard resources, but also handle some more deeper problems I encountered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade from Rails 2 to Rails 3, first make sure to upgrade to the latest 2.3 version.

Then, before migrating, there is a [list of changes you can make](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/07/the-way-to-rails-3/) to make your Rails 2.3 application behaving like a Rails 3 application. Once you applied these changes, chances are the number of issues will be smaller and you can upgrade to Rails 3.

Once you installed Rails 3, use the [rails_upgrade](https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade) plugin to check the incompatibilities and fix them.